# check if image does NOT exist then hide a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

If there is an image in the div then hide the div. But if the image does exist then i need to keep the div visable.

But its not working. Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="FeatureBox">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="productInfoGrid">
          <div id="ProductIconsTitle">
            <p>PRODUCT FEATURES</p>
          </div><img width="563" height="337" src="http://www.preserveshop.co.uk/images/black-jam-jar-lid-58mm.jpg" alt="http://www.preserveshop.co.uk/images/black-jam-jar-lid-58mm.jpg" style="cursor: -moz-zoom-in"><div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
if ($("#div#productInfoGrid:not(img)").length) {
    $("#productInfoGrid").hide();
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**:http://jsfiddle.net/wJgpr/3/

Comment: updated my jsfiddle and code slightly... problem still exists.

Comment: An element **cannot** have two IDs: `#div#productInfoGrid`. Also, `:not()` is not the right selector for this. Take your time and browse through the jQuery API docs: http://api.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("div#productInfoGrid").has('img').hide();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wJgpr/12/)**

#### Note

`$("#div#productInfoGrid:not(img)")` should be `$("div#productInfoGrid:not(img)")`

Answer (score 5):

```
if ( !$("#productInfoGrid").has("img") ) {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

or simpler

```
$("#productInfoGrid").not(':has("img")').hide();​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wwWCh/)

Comment: what was wrong with my code? will this work if there IS an image and if there ISNT one too?

Comment: yes, it will - it checks if the `div` has NO (note the `!`) images and hides it if true. If an image found - nothing happens and the `div` remains visible

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($("#productInfoGrid img").length == 0) {
    $("#productInfoGrid").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) **(Reference: http://api.jquery.com/find/)**

```
if ($("#productInfoGrid").find('img').length == 0) {
    $("#productInfoGrid").hide();
}
​
```