# How to hide a DIV when image not found?

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a site and a problem occured. I want that if one image exists, the other DIV's should hide.

If all 5 images exist, then no DIV should hide.

If less than 5 images exist, then remaining DIV's should hide.

I'm not an expert in jquery, so looking for short jquery snippet, which could do so.

Here is html.

```
<div class="screenshoto">
<div id="scr"><a href="{$screenshot_1}"><img title="{$p_name} {$p_vers} screenshot" alt="{$p_name} {$p_vers} screenshot" style="max-width:615px;" src="{$screenshot_1}"></a></div> </br>
<div id="scr"><a href="{$screenshot_2}"><img title="{$p_name} {$p_vers} screenshot" alt="{$p_name} {$p_vers} screenshot" style="max-width:615px;" src="{$screenshot_2}"></a></div> </br>
<div id="scr"><a href="{$screenshot_3}"><img title="{$p_name} {$p_vers} screenshot" alt="{$p_name} {$p_vers} screenshot" style="max-width:615px;" src="{$screenshot_3}"></a></div> </br>
<div id="scr"><a href="{$screenshot_4}"><img title="{$p_name} {$p_vers} screenshot" alt="{$p_name} {$p_vers} screenshot" style="max-width:615px;" src="{$screenshot_4}"></a></div> </br>
<div id="scr"><a href="{$screenshot_5}"><img title="{$p_name} {$p_vers} screenshot" alt="{$p_name} {$p_vers} screenshot" style="max-width:615px;" src="{$screenshot_5}"></a></div> </br>
</div>
```

I have searched Stack Overflow but a relevant ([check if image does NOT exist then hide a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575914/check-if-image-does-not-exist-then-hide-a-div)) snippet found and did not worked.

Can some one help working code with respect to my html. Thanks.

Comment: Well, not sure what `{$screenshot_1}` through `{$screenshot_5}` are supposed to represent, not sure what language you are even using for this here.  Also, why do you have the same `ids` on all 5 `div` tags?

Comment: these {$screenshot_1} to {$screenshot_5} are 5 images.

Comment: Oh, so you are just putting that in there for the sake of this question right?  But that is not what's really in there right?  I think, in order to help, it would be better to have the actual code you are using live...

Comment: `</br>` should be `<br />` or `<br>`.

Comment: Just want that if any image i.e src=="" becomes empty, the div should hide.

Comment: Why would images not exist? Are they dynamically inserted somehow, or modified/hidden on the fly, or are you looking for a "file not found" on the server error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var breakLoop = false; //initialising 
    $('.screenshoto div').each(function(){
        if(breakLoop ) return false; //breaking the loop if image is missing
        if($(this).find('img').length == 0){
           $(this).hide();
           breakLoop = true;
        }
    });
```