# i want to hide image div having no images using php

Tags: php, html, styles

I want to hide my html div when there are no images, and show it when I have an image. How can I do this using php?
 this is my code

```
<?php
   $imgsql=mysqli_query($link,"select eve_pic,eve_pic2,eve_pic3,eve_pic4 from event_tbl");

?>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" <?php  if(mysqli_num_rows($imgsql)>0){ 
                      $imgrow=mysqli_fetch_array($imgsql);
               ?> style="visibility:visible;"<?php }?> <?php else { ?> style="display:none" <?php}?> >
                    <div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_wrap>
                              <div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_img>
                        <div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_btn>
                                 <a href=#sz_portfolio_003_4_col data-backdrop=true data-slide-to=0 data-toggle=modal>
                            <img src="admin/uploads/eventpics/<?php echo $imgrow['eve_pic'];?>" alt="sz_portfolio_003_01" width="200px" height="200px" class="imagen"/></a>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: simple use if condition to check url exist or not and then display html.

Comment: which `<div>` are you referring to? you have 3 `<div>`  there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if image does NOT exist then hide a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575914/check-if-image-does-not-exist-then-hide-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an If Statement to get what you want. To know more about If statement read it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Change this:

```
    <?php
   $imgsql=mysqli_query($link,"select eve_pic,eve_pic2,eve_pic3,eve_pic4 from event_tbl");

?>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" <?php  if(mysqli_num_rows($imgsql)>0){ 
                      $imgrow=mysqli_fetch_array($imgsql);
               ?> style="visibility:visible;"<?php }?> <?php else { ?> style="display:none" <?php}?> >
                    <div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_wrap>
                              <div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_img>
                        <div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_btn>
                                 <a href=#sz_portfolio_003_4_col data-backdrop=true data-slide-to=0 data-toggle=modal>
                            <img src="admin/uploads/eventpics/<?php echo $imgrow['eve_pic'];?>" alt="sz_portfolio_003_01" width="200px" height="200px" class="imagen"/></a>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

To this:

```
<?php
    $imgsql=mysqli_query($link,"select eve_pic,eve_pic2,eve_pic3,eve_pic4 from event_tbl");
    if( mysqli_num_rows($imgsql)>0 ){ 
        $imgrow=mysqli_fetch_array($imgsql);
    }

    if(!empty($imgrow['eve_pic'])){
?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_wrap>
            <div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_img>
                <div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_btn>
                    <a href=#sz_portfolio_003_4_col data-backdrop=true data-slide-to=0 data-toggle=modal>
                    <img src="admin/uploads/eventpics/<?php echo $imgrow['eve_pic'];?>" alt="sz_portfolio_003_01" width="200px" height="200px" class="imagen"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="<?php 

                  if (mysqli_num_rows($imgsql)>0){ 
                  $imgrow=mysqli_fetch_array($imgsql);
                  echo "display:block;"}

                  else { echo "display:none"};

             ?>"...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this to:

```
<?php if(!empty($imgrow['eve_pic']))?>{
<div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_wrap>
    <div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_img>
        <div class=sz_portfolio_003_trig_btn>
            <a href=#sz_portfolio_003_4_col data-backdrop=true data-slide-to=0 data-toggle=modal>
            <img src="admin/uploads/eventpics/<?php echo $imgrow['eve_pic'];?>" alt="sz_portfolio_003_01" width="200px" height="200px" class="imagen"/></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

If Image exists then only show div.